# How do I login to a website using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" class="buttonBase create_account_button_disabled big orangeButton light js-loginSubmit" value="Log In" style="">
```

I've been trying to log in to this website for a while now and I can't seem to figure it out. 
I need to "click" the element I pasted above.

self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit"][@type="submit"]').click()

When I use the code I've pasted above it doesn't report any errors but it seems like nothing happens when it runs.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit1: It is tagged as an event when you inspect it

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("signinSubmit").click()
```

By using the string above the locator finds the button but when I run the script I encounter this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div id="signinSubmit" class="orangeButton buttonBase js-loginSubmitModal"> could not be scrolled into view
```

How would I go about resolving this?

Comment: What is the url of this page I need more info to be able to help

Answer (score 0):

could be below reasons which restrict you to click on button.

1. May be that element must be inside iframes.
2. Might be xpath you are using is not unique
3. Put some wait before clicking on element

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of login into twitter, the difference is I do it by pressing the ENTER button instead clicking on SUBMIT.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')

email = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email')
email.clear()
email.send_keys(EMAIL)
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'pass')
password.clear()
password.send_keys(PASSWORD)

password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # Login with ENTER button
```

Comment: self.driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password, Keys.RETURN)

Doesn't seem to be working either

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
find_element_by_class_name("js-loginSubmit")
```

If it does not work it may be because it has this class `create_account_button_disabled` 
Can you use it manualy

Comment: That didn't work either. I can do it manually but it kinda defeats the purpose as I am bound to run into other issues in the future.